# Migrating an Ubuntu 1804 (MBR/GPT) qcow2 image to a physical partition (GPT)

Tags: virtualization, 18.04

Is it possible to migrate an Ubuntu Mate 1804 from a qcow2 image to a physical partition? My approach was-

```
$ sudo apt install libguestfs-tools 
$ sudo guestmount -a /media/user/images/mate1804.qcow2 -m /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

and then I mounted the physical partition to another mountpoint (`/tmp/test`) and just copied the whole /mnt directory to that physical mount point like this

```
$ sudo cp -p -R /mnt/* /tmp/test/
$ sudo update-grub
```

But when I try to boot mate1804, I think it still looking for the VM's partition UUID, so I ended up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa5zt.jpg). I tried to reinstall the kernel on a chroot env using an Ubuntu 16.04 like this-

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt 
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt /pts
$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt /sys
$ sudo mount --bind /run /mnt /run
$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt /proc
$ chroot /mnt
$ apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-headers-generic linux-firmware linux-base linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic pptp-linux syslinux util-linux
```

but still ended up [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa5zt.jpg). I have tried

```
sudo qemu-img convert -p -O raw /media/user/images/mate1804.qcow2 /dev/sdb8
```

but it corrupts the GPT partition table as MBR partition contamination and even with GPT type qcow2 image, it just corrupts the partition.

**N.B.** That qcow2 image has a swap and a root partition combined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the transfer is easiest via a tarball, that you store in some separate partition (maybe on an external drive). It will also serve as a backup.

- Boot from another drive, mount the root partition and change directory to the mountpoint and run

  ```
  sudo tar -cvzf storage/file.tar.gz .
  ```

  Make a tarball from each partition with files (the root partition, maybe also a boot partition and a home partition).
- After that you prepare your GPT file partition table and file system(s).

  This  link may help: [help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)
- Extract from the tarfile(s). When booted from another drive, mount the root partition of the new GPT drive, change directory to the mountpoint and run

  ```
  sudo tar -xvf storage/file.tar.gz
  ```
- Tweak the transferred system, so that the UUIDs of the new partitions match those in the files of the new GPT system

  - `/mountpoint/etc/fstab`
  - `/mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

This can be done either by modifying the UUIDs or by modifying the files. Since there should be no risk of confusion with the virtual system, maybe it is easiest to modify the UUIDs of the partitions. You can do that with `tune2fs` for an ext4 file system and with `mkswap` for a swap partition.

---

If this does not work, maybe it is easiest to make a fresh install and only transfer the `/home` directory (into a home partition on the target system and use 'Something else' alias manual partitioning in the installer).

Comment: With gpt, it is not just UUIDs but GUIDs that must match within system, but not be identical if system copy. The gpt system has GUID in primary & backup partition tables and in a partition. All three then must match. Reinstall & data copy is probably best solution. You may be able to change UUIDs & update GUID with gdisk, but not sure how.